# How does one change Vivado IP signal types?

Tags: fpga, vivado, zynq

The Xilinx IP block called Utility Buffer allows the designer to convert one single-ended signal to a differential signal pair (among other things).

However, the block expects the input and output ports of the block to be of type 'clk', which then causes these signals to use clock routing resources instead during implementation.

I have attempted to edit the source code outside of Vivado, but Vivado is somehow forcing type 'clk' on these ports anyway.

Is there a way to force these ports into a certain type? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Anything you use "rising_edge" or "falling_edge" (or their Verilog equivalents) is interpreted as a clock signal.

Comment: Is this generally true in FPGAland?

Comment: It's true for Xilinx at least and at least one other manufacturer (probably Altera but possibly Lattice, I can't remember). All signals associated with those keywords automatically get their own dedicated clock routing network on the FPGA so don't use those keywords just because you want something to happen on a rising or falling edge. I'm just throwing this out there in case it's related since there might be something else going on in the IP block. I don't know what the formal type "clk" refers to exactly in your context and it's strange if inputs and outputs are being typed as such.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, so my instincts were telling me not to 'waste' resources routing things as clock signals when they were data. But if edge-generated behavior is clock behavior, then it's not an issue...

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't route things on the dedicated clock routing layers if they are data since you might only have 8 of those (and eight is quite a lot as far as that goes). If you want to detect edges on non-clock signals you should be doing something like saving the current signal state and comparing the current state to the previous state for a change.

Comment: If I interpreted your question correctly though, you are that the IP block is treating ALL signals input and output as clock signals (which would mean using the clock routing network) which wouldn't make sense, especially for outputs. So it seems something has been lost in translation or missing.

Comment: The differential signaling variants of Vivado's Utility Buffer block expect type clock inputs and produce type clock outputs. It doesn't make much sense to me. Example: WARNING: [BD 41-1731] Type mismatch between connected pins: /HMI_SPI_MISO_ds_buf/IBUF_OUT(clk) and /HMI_SPI_master/miso(undef) ... The ds_buf block is Xilinx's Utility Buffer and SPI_master is my block.

Comment: That doesnt sound like the same thing I was referring to, so you can just file away what I said in your head for future use. The datasheet for the IP block (PB043) does say the inputs are type "CLK_IN_D". It doesn't list any outputs as that type though. Note that this sounds like a *HARDWARE* IP block so it doesn't play by the same rules as generic FPGA logic fabric. That would explain why changing things in the source code don't work since it's already set in stone in the hardware. Just give the IP block what it wants.